# Must a same WooCommerce hook uses always the same set of parameters?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, arguments, hook-woocommerce

I'm still new with actions and filters. I noticed that people are using different parameters for the same hook. The filter is `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data`

The below is from [here](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_add_cart_item_data/) and it uses THREE parameters - `$cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id`

```
// define the woocommerce_add_cart_item_data callback 
function filter_woocommerce_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) { 
    // make filter magic happen here... 
    return $cart_item_data; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'filter_woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 10, 3 );
```

And the below is from [here](https://www.kathyisawesome.com/add-a-custom-field-to-woocommerce-product/) and it uses TWO parameters and the first one is `$cart_item` not `$cart_item_data` like above. Is that possible?

```
function kia_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $product_id ){

    if( isset( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) ) {
        $cart_item['custom_option'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_custom_option'] );
    }

    return $cart_item;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'kia_add_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Number of arguments:** With [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) or [`add_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) WordPress functions, you can define (optionally) as 4th argument the number of arguments (variables) you are using (passing) in the hooked function.

Example of different cases for `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` filter hook below:

- With 3 arguments declared and available:

  ```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'filter_add_cart_item_data', 10, 3 ); 
  function filter_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) { 
      // make filter magic happen here... 
      return $cart_item_data; 
  };
  ```
- With 2 arguments declared and available:

  ```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'filter_add_cart_item_data', 10, 2 ); 
  function filter_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) { 
      // make filter magic happen here... 
      return $cart_item_data; 
  };
  ```
- With 1 argument declared and available:

  ```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'filter_add_cart_item_data', 10, 1 ); 
  function filter_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data ) { 
      // make filter magic happen here... 
      return $cart_item_data; 
  };
  ```
- With 1 argument available and used (but not declared):

  ```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'filter_add_cart_item_data' ); 
  function filter_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data ) { 
      // make filter magic happen here... 
      return $cart_item_data; 
  };
  ```
- With a pre-made dedicated WordPress function, *(here [`__return_false`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__return_false/))*

  ```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', '__return_false' );
  ```

---

2) **You can change the variable names passed to a hooked function** without any problem.

So for example this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 3 ); 
function add_custom_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) { 

    if ( isset($_POST['material']) && in_array( $product_id, array(21,57) ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['custom_data'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['material'] );

    return $cart_item_data; 
};
```

is the same thing than this one:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'filter_woocommerce_add_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 2 ); 
function filter_woocommerce_add_custom_cart_item_data( $data, $post_id ) { 

    if ( isset($_POST['material']) && in_array( $post_id, array(21,57) ) ) {
        $data['custom_data'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['material'] );

    return $data; 
};
```

Both will do the same.

Comment: Merci beaucoup! For #2 above, do you mean I could only rename the variables or could I change the variable data from cart_item_data to cart_item instead? I actually need to change the data of cart_item using this hook.